# Unable to get the result from web api action called from angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, angular6

I am trying to get the UserProfile details by passing the user's email, in Angular, by POST request to WebApi, but I am unable to get the data. I am getting this error: *unexpected end of input.*

Here is the method which makes the call:

```
getUserProfile(resourceEmail: string): Observable<any> {
debugger
return this.http.post<UserVM>(this.getAPI('FetchUserProfile')+'/? emailId='+resourceEmail,
  this.httpOptions).pipe(
    map(data => data),
    catchError(this.handleError<any>())
  );
 }
```

controller action code

```
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    [System.Web.Mvc.Route("ApiWithAction")]
    public HttpResponseMessage FetchUserProfile(string emailId)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, _userProfileService.GetUserProfile(emailId));
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //client.TrackException(ex.InnerException);
            return null; //need to check and confirm what needs return to UI               
        }
    }
```

subscribe code

```
 getBookingList() {
this.bookingListSubscription = this.restService.getCompletedListForGrid(this.booking).subscribe(
  data => {

    this.bookingList = data;

    this.bookingList.forEach((element) => {
      element.StartDate = new Date(element.StartDate),
        element.EndDate = new Date(element.EndDate);
    });
    this.gridData = this.bookingList;
    this.spinner.hide();
  });
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Post your code related to subscribe

Comment: @Pradeep Jain I have updated the question with subscribe code

Comment: have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: yaa i tried but getting same error

Comment: Can you create stackblizt for the same?

Comment: Try replacing this.http.post<UserVM>(...) to this.http.post<any>(...).

Comment: can you paste the json that the API is returning?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are assigning a value in a wrong way, Better to assign a value like -

```
this.restService.getUserProfile("")
 .subscribe(data => {
    this.bookingListSubscription
    .... other code
 });
```